# How to Properly Split Survey Responses, in R

Tags: r, dplyr

In survey statistical data, multiple response labels may be recorded in a single column when multiple responses are allowed to a question.

In analyzing such data, you may want to store multiple responses in separate columns, necessitating string splitting.

Run the following code as a sample.

```r
smp <- data.frame(
  x = c("1,2,3", "2,5,9", "1,5", "2,7,8,9,10")
)
smp
#>            x
#> 1      1,2,3
#> 2      2,5,9
#> 3        1,5
#> 4 2,7,8,9,10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In this data, each row represents the responses of a different respondent, and the analyst knows how many choices there are in total, but does not know which or how many responses will be selected.

The result of dividing this appropriately should look like this

```r
out <- data.frame(
  d_1 = c(1,NA,1,NA),
  d_2 = c(2,2,NA,2),
  d_3 = c(3,NA,NA,NA),
  d_4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
  d_5 = c(NA,5,5,NA),
  d_6 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA),
  d_7 = c(NA,NA,NA,7),
  d_8 = c(NA,NA,NA,8),
  d_9 = c(NA,9,NA,9),
  d_10 = c(NA,NA,NA,10)
)
out
#>   d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5 d_6 d_7 d_8 d_9 d_10
#> 1   1   2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
#> 2  NA   2  NA  NA   5  NA  NA  NA   9   NA
#> 3   1  NA  NA  NA   5  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
#> 4  NA   2  NA  NA  NA  NA   7   8   9   10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is there a good way to arrange the data into this form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A truth table perhaps, in base R

```
smp <- data.frame(
  x = c("1,2,3", "2,5,9", "1,5", "2,7,8,9,10")
)
smp_mtx <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 10)

for (i in 1:nrow(smp)) {
smp_mtx[i, which(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) %in% as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(smp[i, ], split = ','))) == TRUE)] <- TRUE
}
smp_mtx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[2,]   NA TRUE   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA TRUE    NA
[3,] TRUE   NA   NA   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[4,]   NA TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

my mistake here was introducing the 'truth table' rather than going directly to populating the char elements against a df

```
 smp_int_df <- data.frame(matrix(NA_integer_, nrow =4, ncol = 10))
smp_int_df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA

for (i in 1:nrow(smp_int_df)) {
 smp_int_df[i, which(c(1:10) %in% as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(smp[i, ],split=','))))] <- c(1:10)[which(c(1:10) %in% as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(smp[i, ],split=','))))] 
 }
smp_int_df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA
2 NA  2 NA NA  5 NA NA NA  9  NA
3  1 NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA  NA
4 NA  2 NA NA NA NA  7  8  9  10
```

then you can name things (cols) what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This not elegant function can give the expected result to you.

```
split_survey <- function(data){
  df <- data
  
  val <- df %>% 
    tidyr::separate_rows(x, sep=",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
    range() 
  
  Names <- paste0("d_", seq(val[1], val[2]))
  df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, list(Names)))
  names(df) <- df[1,]
  df[1:nrow(data), ] <- NA
  
  values <- lapply(strsplit(data$x, ","), function(x) paste0("d_",sub("\\s+", "", x)))

  for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
    ind <- names(df) %in%  values[[i]] 
    df[i, ind] <- as.integer(sub("\\D+", "", values[[i]]))
  }
  
  df[] <- lapply(df, as.integer)

  return(df)
}


split_survey(smp)
 d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4 d_5 d_6 d_7 d_8 d_9 d_10
1   1   2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
2  NA   2  NA  NA   5  NA  NA  NA   9   NA
3   1  NA  NA  NA   5  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
4  NA   2  NA  NA  NA  NA   7   8   9   10
```

It will work if `smp` only contains one variable named `x` as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `tidyverse` solution using a potpourri of functions from the `tidyverse` family:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

smp %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(x) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>% 
  complete(x = first(x):last(x)) %>% 
  mutate(x = paste0("d_", x)) %>% 
  count(id, x) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = n) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= n()-1) %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, ~case_when(. == 1 ~ readr::parse_number(cur_column())))) %>% 
  select(order(readr::parse_number(names(.))), -id)
```

```
    d_1   d_2   d_3   d_4   d_5   d_6   d_7   d_8   d_9  d_10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2    NA     2    NA    NA     5    NA    NA    NA     9    NA
3     1    NA    NA    NA     5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4    NA     2    NA    NA    NA    NA     7     8     9    10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach, where I used the join

### data

```r
smp <- data.frame(
  x = c("1,2,3", "2,5,9", "1,5", "2,7,8,9,10")
)
```

### code

```r
library(tidyverse)

dummmy <- data.frame(x=1:10) %>% mutate(x=as.character(x))


df <- tibble(x=strsplit(smp$x,',')) %>% mutate(len=row_number(), value=x) %>% 
  unnest(c(x,value)) %>% 
  full_join(dummmy, by='x') %>% 
  mutate(name=paste0('d_',x), x=as.numeric(x), value=as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>%   
  pivot_wider(len, names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% select(-len) %>% 
  mutate(sum=rowSums(across(starts_with('d')),na.rm=T)) %>% 
  filter(sum>0) %>% select(-sum)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 10
    d_1   d_2   d_3   d_4   d_5   d_6   d_7   d_8   d_9  d_10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     1    NA    NA    NA     5    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     2    NA    NA     5    NA    NA    NA     9    NA
4    NA     2    NA    NA    NA    NA     7     8     9    10
```